# Problems with HTMLDocument

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-crawler

I am new this web crawling world. So Anyone worked on any web application for web crawl ? I need help if someone used asp.net & C# **not** VB.NET windows form.

I have a default webform with 3 text boxes and a button and this is the Code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Net;

using System.IO;




public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    String Rstring;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WebRequest myWebRequest;
        WebResponse myWebResponse;
        String URL = TextBox1.Text;

        myWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(URL);
        myWebResponse = myWebRequest.GetResponse();//Returns a response from an Internet resource

        Stream streamResponse = myWebResponse.GetResponseStream();//return the data stream from the internet
        //and save it in the stream

        StreamReader sreader = new StreamReader(streamResponse);//reads the data stream
        Rstring = sreader.ReadToEnd();//reads it to the end
        String Links = GetContent(Rstring);//gets the links only

        TextBox2.Text = Rstring;
        TextBox3.Text = Links;
        streamResponse.Close();
        sreader.Close();
        myWebResponse.Close();

    }


    //public ISet<string> GetNewLinks(string content)
    //{
    //    Regex regexLink = new Regex("(?<=<a\\s*?href=(?:'|\"))[^'\"]*?(?=(?:'|\"))");

    //    ISet<string> newLinks = new HashSet<string>();
    //    foreach (var match in regexLink.Matches(content))
    //    {
    //        if (!newLinks.Contains(match.ToString()))
    //            newLinks.Add(match.ToString());
    //    }

    //    return newLinks;
    //}

    private String GetContent(String Rstring)
    {
        String sString = "";
        HTMLDocument d = new HTMLDocument();
        IHTMLDocument2 doc = (IHTMLDocument2)d;
        doc.write(Rstring);

        IHTMLElementCollection L = doc.links;

        foreach (IHTMLElement links in L)
        {
            sString += links.getAttribute("href", 0);
            sString += "/n";
        }
        return sString;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a Old question but it never got answered so here goes nothing, maybe this will help someone.

I managed to make your code work and got all the links by changing the way you got your content with this:

```
    private string GetContent(String Rstring)
    {
        String sString = "";
        String temp = "";
        mDocument.LoadHtml(Rstring);
        IEnumerable<HtmlNode> links = mDocument.DocumentNode.Descendants("a");

        foreach (HtmlNode link in links)
        {
            temp = link.GetAttributeValue("href", "");
            if (temp.StartsWith("https://") || temp.StartsWith("http://"))
                sString += temp + "\n";
            else
                continue;
        }

        return sString;
    }
```

So I go get all the a elements in the page then if they have a valid link I add it to the string and return it.